# Performancing regex search on MongoDb collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection with 546.8m documents.
and I need to search some documents that matches the Username property.

I create this piece of foce

```
 FilterDefinition<ProfileEntity> f = Builders<ProfileEntity>.Filter.Regex("Username", new BsonRegularExpression(profileName,"i"));

                var profilesList = await collection.Find(f).Limit(25).ToListAsync();
```

But this is taking soo long time.

What can I do for a better performance?

Creating a index would increase the performance ina big scale?

The limit of records is fixed 25.

Using the client comand line or MongoDB Compass the search is soo fast .

When using  with c# is soo slow.

Of course the between them has to be different . But I can't believe that is too much

Any ideas?

Comment: [Index Use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) - *Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a “prefix expression” ....  A regular expression is a “prefix expression” if it starts with a caret (^) or a left anchor (\A), followed by a string of simple symbols"* That's the main details, but basically understanding that your "unbound" search is a bad thing. Ideally search from string beginning with `'^'  + profilename` for optimal index performance. If you cannot, then you're basically out of luck. Design based on how things work.